# UNIX Shell Loop through user input

Tags: shell, unix

I want the user to choose one of the following: l,m,c or a. If the user puts in any other input, it will tell them 'invalid input' and ask them to enter again. I'm having problems trying to get it to loop back if the user enters an invalid input. I'm thinking I need to use a while loop, but I'm not sure.

```
echo "Enter the file name: " 
read file

echo "Count lines, words, characters or all three (l, m, c, a)? "
read variable

NUMOFLINES=$(wc -l < $file)
NUMOFWORDS=$(wc -w < $file)
NUMOFCHARACTERS=$(wc -c < $file)

if [ $variable == "l" ]
    then
        echo "The file" $file "has" $NUMOFLINES "lines"

elif [ $variable == "m" ]
    then

        echo "The file" $file "has" $NUMOFWORDS "words"

elif [ $variable == "c" ]
    then

        echo "The file" $file "has" $NUMOFCHARACTERS "characters"

elif [ $variable == "a" ]
    then
        echo "The file" $file "has" $NUMOFLINES "lines"
        echo "The file" $file "has" $NUMOFWORDS "words"
        echo "The file" $file "has" $NUMOFCHARACTERS "characters"

elif [ $variable != "*" ] #|| [ $variable != "m" ] || [ $variable != "c" ] || 
[ $variable != "a" ]
    then
        echo "Invalid input"

    fi
```

Comment: To loop use a loop -- `while`...`do`...`done`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `select` loop (with a `case` statement to reduce some of the verbosity). (Using `==` with `[ ... ]` tells me you are using `bash`):

```
IFS= read -r -p "Enter the file name: " file
numlines=$(wc -l < "$file")
numwords=$(wc -w < "$file")
numchars=$(wc -c < "$file")
select variable in l m c a; do
    case $variable in
        l) echo "The file $file has $numlines lines"
           ;;
        m) echo "The file $file has $numwords words"
           ;;
        c) echo "The file $file has $numchars characters"
           ;;
        a) echo "The file $file has $numlines lines"
           echo "The file $file has $numwords words"
           echo "The file $file has $numchars characters"
           ;;
        *) echo "Invalid input"
           ;;
    esac
done
```